# Magento 2: Need to override loadAttributeOptions()

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I need to override this function loadAttributeOptions() in my custom module.

```
File - /var/www/html/dg/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product/Subselect.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a module and write a preference for override `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Subselect` in di.xml file like below:

```
 <preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Subselect" type="ModuleNamespace\Modulename\Model\Roule\Condition\Product\Subselect"/>
```

Once the preference is done, you can write down the subselect file and can override the function `loadAttributeOptions()` in that file.

Comment: Not working I already tried this